# nginx httpsubmodule to replace html content

Tags: http, static, nginx

I just came across the nginx httpsubmodule. I think it might be what could help me do this.

I have HTML pages which are static and I want to use the uri portion in the output html.
for e.g. my static URL is http://static.mydomain.com/pic1234.html so in the page I want to display the word "pic1234".
I cannot use javascript as I want to generate HTML meta data for the static page.

Can this be done? if so how? I am not able to find any examples. All I found was this http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpSubModule

note that I have no cgi or programs on the static file serving nginx server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have created a simple example. Using this configuration, nginx replaces `__name__` token in the html page with the file name ("pic1234" in this case) of the requested html:

**nginx configuration:**

```
server {
        listen   80;
        server_name localhost;

        root D:/Development/public;
        sub_filter_once off;

        location / {
            if ($uri ~* /(\w+)\.html$) {
               set $filename "$1";
            }
            sub_filter "__name__" $filename;
            try_files $uri $uri/ ;
        }
}
```

**D:/Development/public/pic1234.html:**

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>__name__</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Contents of __name__:</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

You can find the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/2950723)

Comment: Can I use this to replace `__name__` with environment variable?